# Woocommerce - Sorting Custom Product Category Meta

Tags: woocommerce

I want to sort the custom meta content that I have created for the product category. Content is usually text. My aim is to sort the empty ones in order to easily detect them. If text is available, it can give priority to letter length. I can't get any changes with the following codes. Thanks.

```
function list_fill( $columns, $column, $id ) {
if ( $column = 'my_custom_column' ) {
        $columns = esc_html( get_term_meta($id, '_my_custom_data', true) );
    }
    return $columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_product_cat_custom_column', 'list_fill' , 10, 3);

function sortlist( $columns ) {
    $columns['my_custom_column'] = 'my_custom_column';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_cat_sortable_columns', 'sortlist' ); 

function sortlist_orderby( $query ) {  

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');  

    if( 'my_custom_column' == $orderby ) {  
        $query->set('meta_key','_my_custom_data');  
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');  
    }  
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sortlist_orderby' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i usualy register new column.

```
// Add New column
function my_add_new_columns($columns) {
    $new_columns = array(
        'my_custom_column' => esc_html__( 'Custom Column', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    return array_merge($columns,$new_columns);
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_cat_columns',  'my_add_new_columns',10,1 );
```

The rest of the code should be fine but in case here is a full example how i register column, populate values and sort.

```
// Add New column
function my_add_new_columns($columns) {
    $new_columns = array(
        'custom_column' => esc_html__( 'Custom Column', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    return array_merge($columns,$new_columns);
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_cat_columns',  'my_add_new_columns',10,1 );

// Add data to sort
function custom_column_data($argument, $columnName, $termID) {
    if ( $columnName == 'custom_column' ) {
        echo get_term_meta( $termID, '_product_cat_thumb', true );
    }
}
add_action('manage_product_cat_custom_column','custom_column_data',10,3);


//Make column sortable
function custom_sortable_column() {
    $columns['custom_column'] = 'custom_column';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_cat_sortable_columns', 'custom_sortable_column' );

//Config how your sorting should work
function custom_column_orderby($query) {
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );
    if ( 'custom_column' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','_product_cat_thumb');  
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');  
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_column_orderby' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I guess I keep getting similar result. I don't understand how you did the sorting. Because it's like he's spliced the empty colons together. I added screenshots.https://ibb.co/hBRqmsD
https://ibb.co/d0KrVx9

Comment: I didnt do the sorting you want. You have to first check how long is the content for each term then sort term ids ASC or DESC and then run the query sort by term ID not meta. Another way is to have custom meta field that calculate how big is the text and use that instead and change meta_value to meta_value_num . Current sort will just put empty below or above.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. But I tried to edit with meta_value_num, I couldn't get the result I mentioned. I continue to research on the subject, I hope to reach the conclusion.

Comment: U cant just change to meta_value_num. Like i explained first u have to know how long a text is and then sort term ids or have custom meta field to each category with number you can automate it to check the text or manualy put value and then if this value is a number use meta_value_num.